# VBA - Optimizing locating index of first row on each page of Word Table via. Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a bunch of word documents that each contain a single table, some of which hold an exorbitant amount of data (20,000+ rows perhaps) and hence can stretch over hundreds of pages long.

With that being said, I found a VBA word macro that can display all row indices that start every page. For example, the macro will display 100 integers for a table that stretches for 100 pages. This is exactly what I need but for various reasons, the macro runs very slow. Furthermore, it runs even slower when I adapted the code and embedded it into an excel macro (to use on a word object).

So my question is - can this macro be somehow optimized? I suppose the looping is causing the problem. Many thanks for your input!

```
Sub TableRowData()
    'define meaningful names to use for array's first dimension
    Const pgnum = 1
    Const startrow = 2
    Const endrow = 3

    Dim data() As Long  ' array to hold data
    Dim rw As Row       ' current row of table
    Dim rownum As Long  ' the index of rw in table's rows
    Dim datarow As Long ' current value of array's second dimension
    Dim rg As Range     ' a range object for finding the page where rw starts

    'initialization
    ReDim data(3, 1)
    Set rw = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1)
    rownum = 1
    datarow = 1

    'store the page number and row number for the first row of the table
    Set rg = rw.Range
    rg.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    data(pgnum, datarow) = rg.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    data(startrow, datarow) = rownum

    'Step through the remaining rows of the table.
    'Each time the page number changes, store the preceding row as the
    'last row on the previous page; then expand the array and store the
    'page number and row number for the new row.
    While rownum < ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
        Set rw = rw.Next
        rownum = rownum + 1
        Set rg = rw.Range
        rg.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        If rg.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > data(pgnum, datarow) Then
            data(endrow, datarow) = rownum - 1
       
            ReDim Preserve data(3, datarow + 1)
            datarow = datarow + 1
            data(pgnum, datarow) = rg.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            data(startrow, datarow) = rownum
        End If
    Wend

    'finish up with the last row of the table
    data(endrow, datarow) = rownum
     
    Dim msg As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
        msg = msg & data(startrow, i) & vbCr
    Next i
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: If the code in your question is being run from Excel you need to change the declarations for `rw` and `rg` as these are ambiguous. Both Excel and Word contain `Range` and `Row` objects, so you need to prefix the datatype with the library name, i.e. `Word.Range`, `Word.Row`

Comment: Thank you Tim. Yes, in my excel adaption, I did add the prefix - otherwise it wouldn't even run. I also included a reference to the Microsoft Word object model to make life easier. However despite doing all of this, it just runs too slow for the time being. Forget about the 500+ page word document, anything around 100+ pages will take roughly 30-60 minutes. Just a little too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something based on:

```
Sub TableRowData()
Dim Doc As Document, Rng As Range, Data() As Long, i As Long, j As Long, p As Long, r As Long, x As Long
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
With Doc
  With .Tables(1).Range
    i = .Cells(1).Range.Characters.First.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    j = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Range.Characters.Last.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    ReDim Data(3, j - i)
    For p = i To j
      Set Rng = Doc.Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=p)
      Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
      r = Rng.Cells(1).RowIndex
      x = p - i: Data(1, x) = x: Data(2, x) = p: Data(3, x) = r
    Next
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked and it definitely seems faster while I'm running it in word. I will adapt it into excel to see how much more efficiency I get. It seems that you have used the logic proposed by norie to loop through the pages instead of looping through the rows correct?

Comment: Same principles regards processing by page, but developed independently, but I start by getting the table's starting & end page #s so as to limit the pages to process and I don't use .Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber). I've made a minor code refinement to speed up the code just a bit.

Comment: Thanks again. I will get back to you if it slows down again at the excel step. I doubt it though. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, early binding is much faster than late binding and hiding the Word application (or at least the document, if you're opening it in code) will help the code run faster. Messing with Application.ScreenUpdating (for Word) won't deliver any material benefit, though, since you're not editing or scrolling through the document.

Comment: I actually don't know this but it makes sense that the code will run faster if I didn't have to open up the actual word document (since some could be over 100mb in size). Right now in the excel macro, I declare a word application object and then use the WordApp.Documents.Open function to access the word file. In the process of doing so, the document opens up. How would I eliminate this step?

Comment: You cannot avoid opening the documents, but setting WordApp.Visible = False before opening any documents will eliminate all the interface overheads.

Comment: I see. I did manage to adapt it into excel and between opening and processing, it takes roughly 20 minutes for a 35mb word file (file has roughly 350 pages). The prior version where I looped across each line took more than a day hence it is already a huge improvement. I will try the WordApp.Visible = False tip to see how much additional time I can save. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229534/discussion-between-user3624032-and-macropod).

Answer (score 1):

Processing tables row by row is notoriously slow and there is little you can do to speed things up.

One thing that will help is to turn off screen updating. At the start of your routine add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and at the end `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`.

The other thing you can experiment with is using a `For Each` loop. There is some disagreement as to whether or not this method is faster. Having a large table to process will give you a pretty good idea of which is the faster method, but don't expect miracles. Whichever method you adopt you are going to need patience.

```
Sub TableRowData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'define meaningful names to use for array's first dimension
    Const pgnum = 1
    Const startrow = 2
    Const endrow = 3

    Dim data() As Long  ' array to hold data
    Dim rw As Row       ' current row of table
    Dim rownum As Long  ' the index of rw in table's rows
    Dim datarow As Long ' current value of array's second dimension
    'Dim rg As Range     ' a range object for finding the page where rw starts

    'initialization
    ReDim data(3, 1)
    Set rw = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1)
    rownum = 1
    datarow = 1

    'store the page number and row number for the first row of the table
    Set rg = rw.Range
    rg.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    data(pgnum, datarow) = rg.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    data(startrow, datarow) = rownum

    'Step through the remaining rows of the table.
    'Each time the page number changes, store the preceding row as the
    'last row on the previous page; then expand the array and store the
    'page number and row number for the new row.
    'While rownum < ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count
    For Each rw In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows
        'Set rw = rw.Next
        rownum = rownum + 1
        'Set rg = rw.Range
        'rg.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        If rw.Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > data(pgnum, datarow) Then
            data(endrow, datarow) = rownum - 1
       
            ReDim Preserve data(3, datarow + 1)
            datarow = datarow + 1
            data(pgnum, datarow) = rw.Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            data(startrow, datarow) = rownum
        End If
    Next rw
    'Wend

    'finish up with the last row of the table
    data(endrow, datarow) = rownum
     
    Dim msg As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
        msg = msg & data(startrow, i) & vbCr
    Next i
    MsgBox msg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again Tim. I think this made it run slightly faster but as you mentioned, it didn't produce a miracle. The issue here is that I need to continuously run this macro as the word documents get updated all the time. Thus patience really isn't something that I can afford. Other than processing the table row-by-row, do you know of any other strategy to grab these indices?

Comment: Use watches to measure duration to find which lines take longest and then work from there. You access the wdInfomation twice. Maybe storing it in a dim is faster. Also consider the  array redims. You know the nu pages so why redim so often? You don't know the impact unless you measure with watches.  You can also test with lists instead. One to try out is looping rows of the first column (if table is uniform). Plenty to try but use watches.

Comment: Also consider the algorithm # it goes line by line. So 1000 rows, means 1000 loops. Suppose you jump 5 rows and if you cross a page, go back 1 by 1 until you have the first, that will give you less loops in total. Taking total page count and total row count your algorithm can decide what the step count should be.

Answer (score 1):

How about looping through the pages and getting the row number?

Would that work?

```
Dim doc As Document
Dim rng As Range
Dim pg As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set doc = ThisDocument
    
    
    For pg = 1 To doc.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
        Set rng = doc.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, pg)
        Debug.Print rng.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)
    Next pg
```

Comment: Ohh smart one.  Should work if it's only table rows in the doc

Comment: I think this is a good strategy as the word document only contains a single table - nothing else. There are also no merges whatsoever. However, when I executed this code, it seems to return a value of "-1" on the immediate window. I suppose this isn't the desired result?